# VLCJ: Direct Rendering in VLCJ using EmbeddedMediaPlayer with a CallbackVideoSurface consuming high CPU

Tags: java, swing, libvlc, vlcj

I have successfully rendered a video using EmbeddedMediaPlayer with a CallbackVideoSurface with my own BufferFormatCallback and RenderCallback.

But the issue is in RenderCallback inside display method it creating lots of threads so that is why it is consuming high CPU, I am not able to find what is wrong with my code if anyone can help me it would be great.

Here is my code

**VideoPlayerTest.java**

```
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.factory.MediaPlayerFactory;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.media.MediaRef;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.medialist.MediaList;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.medialist.MediaListRef;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.videosurface.CallbackVideoSurface;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.videosurface.VideoSurfaceAdapters;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.videosurface.callback.BufferFormat;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.videosurface.callback.BufferFormatCallback;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.videosurface.callback.format.RV32BufferFormat;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.list.MediaListPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.list.MediaListPlayerEventAdapter;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.list.PlaybackMode;

public class VideoPlayerTest {

    private static VideoPlayerTest videoPlayerTest;

    private final JFrame frame;

    private final EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent;

    private final EmbeddedMediaPlayer embeddedMediaPlayer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        videoPlayerTest = new VideoPlayerTest();
    }

    public VideoPlayerTest() {
        frame = new JFrame("My First Media Player");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ArrayList<FrameListener> listeners = new ArrayList<FrameListener>();

        MyVideoPanel myVideoPanel = new MyVideoPanel();
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                listeners.add(myVideoPanel);
                super.windowOpened(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
                listeners.remove(myVideoPanel);
                if(listeners.isEmpty())
                {
                    embeddedMediaPlayer.controls().stop();
                    embeddedMediaPlayer.release();
                }
                frame.dispose();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });



        BufferFormatCallback bufferFormatCallback = new BufferFormatCallback() {

            @Override
            public BufferFormat getBufferFormat(int sourceWidth, int sourceHeight) {
                return new RV32BufferFormat(1920, 1080);
            }

            @Override
            public void allocatedBuffers(ByteBuffer[] buffers) {
            }
        };  

        CallbackVideoSurface callbackVideoSurface = new CallbackVideoSurface(bufferFormatCallback, new MyRenderCallback(listeners, 1920, 1080), false, VideoSurfaceAdapters.getVideoSurfaceAdapter());

        mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();

        MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayerFactory();

        embeddedMediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.mediaPlayers().newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
        embeddedMediaPlayer.audio().setVolume(0);

        callbackVideoSurface.attach(embeddedMediaPlayer);

        embeddedMediaPlayer.videoSurface().set(callbackVideoSurface);
        embeddedMediaPlayer.videoSurface().attachVideoSurface();    


        MediaListPlayer mediaListPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.mediaPlayers().newMediaListPlayer();

        mediaListPlayer.events().addMediaListPlayerEventListener(new MediaListPlayerEventAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void nextItem(MediaListPlayer mediaListPlayer, MediaRef item) {
                System.out.println("nextItem()");
            }
        });

        mediaListPlayer.mediaPlayer().setMediaPlayer(embeddedMediaPlayer);

        MediaList mediaList = mediaPlayerFactory.media().newMediaList();
        mediaList.media().add("{Media Path 1}");
        mediaList.media().add("{Media Path 2}");
        mediaList.media().add("{Media Path 3}");

        MediaListRef mediaListRef = mediaList.newMediaListRef();
        try {
            mediaListPlayer.list().setMediaList(mediaListRef);
        }
        finally {
            mediaListRef.release();
        }

        mediaListPlayer.controls().setMode(PlaybackMode.LOOP);

        mediaListPlayer.controls().play();

        frame.setContentPane(myVideoPanel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**MyVideoPanel.java**

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyVideoPanel extends JPanel implements FrameListener {
    private BufferedImage image;
    public void newFrameRecieved(BufferedImage image) {
        this.image = image;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), null);
        g.dispose();
    }
}
```

**FrameListener.java**

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface FrameListener
{
    public void newFrameRecieved(BufferedImage image);
}
```

**MyRenderCallback.java**

I guess issue is in this class of **display** method

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.List;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.base.MediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.videosurface.callback.BufferFormat;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.videosurface.callback.RenderCallback;


public class MyRenderCallback implements RenderCallback
{
    private List<FrameListener> videoSurfaces;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private BufferedImage image;
    private int[] rgbBuffer;

    public MyRenderCallback(List<FrameListener> listeners, int width, int height)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.videoSurfaces = listeners;
        this.image = new BufferedImage(this.width, this.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        rgbBuffer = new int[image.getWidth() * image.getHeight()];
    }

    @Override
    public void display(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, ByteBuffer[] nativeBuffers, BufferFormat bufferFormat) {
        synchronized (this.rgbBuffer) {
            nativeBuffers[0].asIntBuffer().get(rgbBuffer, 0, bufferFormat.getHeight() * bufferFormat.getWidth());
            image.setRGB(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), rgbBuffer, 0, image.getWidth());
        }

        for(FrameListener fl: videoSurfaces) {
            fl.newFrameRecieved(this.image);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it's creating lots of threads? What do you class as high CPU? Why synchronized on the rgbBuffer?

Comment: By the way, that display() method is on a native thread - I hope that newFrameReceived executes very quickly.

Comment: Please check this VisualVM screenshots, https://www.screencast.com/t/FnCLG4cNCV90 https://www.screencast.com/t/YjHNQqECyKi

Comment: I don't have much knowledge about it, is there any way to do this better because when I use only EmbeddedMediaPlayer it consumes only 1 to 2 % of CPU, but I want the video filled in the panel or frame without aspect ratio. can you please help me?

Comment: There is no issue with video playing it is rendering very nice and play without any issue, but CPU consumption is the only issue.

Comment: Honestly I don't see anything too concerning there. your CPU usage is going to be higher with this approach, it's unavoidable as the CPU is doing more work. if that thread graph continued increasing and never came back down i'd be a bit concerned, but threads come and go - it is I believe a feature of how JNA handles callbacks from native code (and that is how vlcj gets media player events).

Comment: Ok, that is very informative, I just want to confirm that my way of rendering video is ok or not, no problem, Thank you for your time and reply on this issue.